# Convert image to black & transparent (paintable) - JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image, paint

example - http://prntscr.com/smgkpt

I wanna convert an image like the right one to the left one. It is basically turning it to transparent with keeping the black border.

(Like kids painting book)

Is there any way to achieve this using JS/CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you'll get to that with css is probably `filter: grayscale(100%)` and adding in some filters for contrast and saturate.

```css
.two{
   filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(2000%) saturate(2000%) ;
}
```

```html
<img class="one" src="https://www.desicomments.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Donald-Duck-Wearing-Blue-Cap.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="two" src="https://www.desicomments.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Donald-Duck-Wearing-Blue-Cap.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware to grayscale but its not enough for me. I've seen a website doing what I am trying to do so there must be a way. I thought of maybe going through pixels and turning them transparent or black, depending on their current color.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something in this line with a combination of filters

```css
img {
    filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(350%) contrast(10000%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO8EQ.png">
```